# How to modify tabs for the secondary menu in a c# web page application

Tags: c#, asp.net, tabs

i am using asp:menu and asp:multiview to get the tab feature on my page that works fine but the tab looks like a long sentence . I would like to do some seperations between the tabs kind of a border or anythiing . I am new to this tab features. I am using 2013 Visual Studio too.
Any help will be appreciated.
please see the attached image of my tabs and give me some suggestions.

My code goes like this .

```
        <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false" OnMenuItemClick="Menu1_MenuItemClick" >
        <Items>
            <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="" Text="Driver" Value="0" Selected="true"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="" Text="Vehicle" Value="1"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="" Text="SOS" Value="2"></asp:MenuItem>
             <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="" Text="ACE" Value="3"></asp:MenuItem>
        </Items>
        <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="Silver" />
    </asp:Menu>
    <asp:MultiView ID="multiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
       <asp:View ID="Tab3" runat="server">
            <asp:Table runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0">
                <asp:TableRow VerticalAlign="Top">
                    <asp:TableCell CssClass="TabArea" Width="100%" BackColor="Silver">
                        <br /> <br />
                        tab view 3 .this is reserved for SOS .
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
        </asp:View>
    </asp:MultiView>
```

I would like to get my menu as Tab1|Tab2|Tab3 
right now my menu looks like Tab1Tab2Tab3

Comment: Use some css. Or you can do style="" within the asp. We have no code so don't see how you are doing this. Code would help

Comment: PLs , I added my code for tab 3 now .

Comment: If you right click on them you can go to properties and set it

Comment: for asp:MenuItem there is no border or background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do the same and the properties didn't have much options that i can play around with so i just came up with a not harmful trick in coding.
Sorry if i am doing something so stupid, i am a fresh bee here and this served my requirement.
my code would be :

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false" OnMenuItemClick="Menu1_MenuItemClick" >
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="" Text="Driver" Value="0" Selected="true"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="|" Value="0" Selectable="false"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="" Text="Vehicle" Value="1"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="|" Value="2" Selectable="false"></asp:MenuItem>            
        <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="" Text="SOS" Value="3"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="|" Value="4" Selectable="false"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="" Text="ACE" Value="5"></asp:MenuItem>   
        <asp:MenuItem Text="|" Value="6" Selectable="false"></asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
    <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="Silver" />

</asp:Menu>
```

This helped me adding a seperator between the menuitems and the mousehover on the symbol | will be not selectable way always.

Hope it will help you too. Have a great time !

Comment: Happy that worked for you too. We can  hope for better answer in future

Comment: @BlackCanery Canery I saw your answer below .. Yeah that works too but it just increase the padding between your menu items ,you wont get the tab1 | tab2 | tab3 |  format as you asked in the question

Comment: I know. I also tried something that i can do with my experience on them.I didnt get any answer for a long time so i settled for the solution i provided now i updated my application. I am so thankful.

Answer (score 1):

```
#MainContent_Menu1 a.static {
      padding-left: 0.45em;
      padding-right: 0.45em;
  }
```

// this will increase the gap between tabs and will look better.